# Unable to improve query performance in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, indexing, query-performance

I am trying to join 9 tables together. The count and index of each tables are given below along with the query. `Green` color in screenshot indicates keys used to join. But please note that I have used another column for `visit_occurrence` table called `visit_occurrence_id` to join but it's not indexed

[image]

```
DROP MATERIALIZED VIEW IF EXISTS cdm.dummy CASCADE;
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW cdm.dummy as
select
f.person_id,f.gender_id
from cdm.visit_occurrence a
left join 
cdm.condition_occurrence b
on a.person_id = b.person_id and a.visit_occurrence_id = 
b.visit_occurrence_id
left join 
cdm.measurement c
on a.person_id = c.person_id and a.visit_occurrence_id = 
c.visit_occurrence_id
left join 
cdm.drug_exposure d
on a.person_id = d.person_id and a.visit_occurrence_id = 
d.visit_occurrence_id
left join 
cdm.procedure_occurrence e
on a.person_id = e.person_id and a.visit_occurrence_id = 
e.visit_occurrence_id
left join 
cdm.person f
on a.person_id = f.person_id 
left join
cdm.observation g
on a.person_id = g.person_id and a.visit_occurrence_id = 
g.visit_occurrence_id
left join
cdm.observation_period h
on a.person_id = g.person_id
left join
cdm.death i
on a.person_id = i.person_id
```

**explain output**

[image]

**explain outpt with enable_nestloop = off;**

[image]

Please note that **visit_occurrence** is the base table. I pick the columns **person_id** and **visit_occurrence_id** from visit_occurrence table to join with other tables as shown in the query. I see that **visit_occurrence_id** used to join (from base table) with other tables isn't a index column (in base table).

a) Is this the reason for slow performance because it's a base table? But in all other tables, the joining keys are used as index as shown in screenshot above(green color indicates - keys used to join)

b) Are the records count an issue?

Can you help me adapt my query to fix this?

Its been running for more than 5-6 hours but not output yet.

Any help is much appreciated. Will be really helpful

Comment: Please show `EXPLAIN` output. I am afraid that query cannot be fast.

Comment: I am using `psql` terminal and the query is currently running. May I know how can I get it? I also have pgadmin. Should I run the query there (which will take long time to complete) and click `explain`?

Comment: Should I abort the query to see `explain` output in pgadmin?

Comment: Even if I use the term `Explain Analyze` before my select clause, it still runs. The problem is it doesn't end and keeps running. So not sure, how can I get the `Explain` output.

Comment: Do `explain` instead of `explain analyze`

Comment: Yes, updating the post now

Comment: You might try setting `enable_nestloop = off` before running your statement, but don't change the parameter globally.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe - Can you guide me on how to do this?

Comment: Should I just use this `enable_nestloop = off` in front of the query? Will this impact the query output anyway?

Comment: Before the command, run `SET enable_nestloop = off;`.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe - Thank you.Updated the post with `explain` output with `enable_nestloop = off`

Comment: Unfortunately this is still running.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe and ADEpt - As this query is still running, I have decided to get a summarised version of one table from here (thinking it might minimize the run time). For which I am trying to do something like this. Can you help me with this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58411769/how-to-generate-summary-statistics-for-each-group-and-transpose-it

Comment: I guess there is no help. This is just a very long query that returns a lot of data.

Comment: Will you be able to help me with other post please?

Comment: If the only data you select is from table "f", then what is the point of all the left joins?  What useful thing can you do with all those rows full of NULLs?

Comment: No, I didn't show the full select clause here as it would be very lengthy. Buy I pick columns from other tables as well...

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe - Can you help me with this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60087614/unable-to-upload-csv-file-to-a-postgresql-database