# How to generate summary statistics for each group and transpose it?

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I have two tables like as shown below

[image]

I was trying something like below

```
select person_id,
   min(value),max(value),count(value),stddev(value)
   percentile_cont(0.25) within group (order by value_as_number asc) as "25pc",
   percentile_cont(0.75) within group (order by value_as_number asc) as "75pc"
from cdm.measurement
group by person_id
```

If a `person doesn't have a specific reading, the value should NA as shown in screenshot below`

I would like to do two things

1) Create as many columns as the number of readings in `Readings` table (has only unique ids). **For example if Readings table has 800 reading ids, we will have 800 * 6 = 4800 columns for a person**. `6 is used here because of min,max,count,stddev,25th percentile,75 percentile`. Name of the column will be `R_name followed by 25%,75%,min,max etc`. Ex: Read_1_25%, Read_1_min

2) If person doesn't have any readings, his value for missing readings will be NA. for example, `person_id = 1 has only R1 reading. So rest of the 4794 (4800 - 6) columns will be NA

I expect my output to be like as shown below. **As the image is wide,Please click on the image to enlarge it.** ignore the correctness of values in my screenshot. format is what I am looking for your help

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by 25%, 75%, and 50%?

Comment: The percentile. My values might be inaccurate. But what I am looking for this output of this form

Comment: Note: there is a key element missing in your table (probably a `date`).

Comment: SQL is not designed for doing things like that. You should use the output of your first query and transpose the rows to columns inside your application when you _display_ the result.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - Now, we have the column names. Is this possible to do now in SQL?

Comment: Hi @a_horse_with_no_name - Can you help me with this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60087614/unable-to-upload-csv-file-to-a-postgresql-database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use conditional aggregation:

```
select person_id,
       count(*) filter (where reading = 'R_1') as cnt_r_1,
       min(value) filter (where reading = 'R_1') as min_r_1,
       max(value) filter (where reading = 'R_1') as max_r_1,
       avg(value) filter (where reading = 'R_1') as avg_r_1,
       stdev(value) filter (where reading = 'R_1') as stdev_r_1,
       count(*) filter (where reading = 'R_2') as cnt_r_2,
       min(value) filter (where reading = 'R_2') as min_r_2,
       max(value) filter (where reading = 'R_2') as max_r_2,
       avg(value) filter (where reading = 'R_2') as avg_r_2,
       stdev(value) filter (where reading = 'R_2') as stdev_r_2,
       . . .
from t
group by person_id;
```

Comment: No, but the problem is I may not know the `R_1 or R_2` for a patient. I mean I may not have a list of all readings. Whatever readings the person has, we have to generate this summary statistics

Comment: So, I will not be able to write/know before hand what `all readings will a person have`

Comment: @SSMK: that's a fundamental restriction in all relational databases and  SQL: the columns of a query must be know to the database _before_ it starts running the query. It's impossible to have a query where the columns (and their data types) are only detected once the statement starts running.

Comment: Here, we know the column. But not the values. Right?

Comment: @SSMK I don't think so; it seems you are saying that we'll have no idea ahead of time what the column names should be in the output.

Comment: @Jeremy - Actually it's not the column names right? What I am saying is `Readings` column can contain any value from `R_1 to R_n`. We might only not know the value but column name is still Readings. Am I right?

Comment: @SSMK We know the columns of the table, but not the output.

Comment: Yeah the output columns will be based on the Input values of `readings` column

Comment: Hello Everyone, I managed to find a way to get more info. I have updated the post.Will you guys be able to help? Now we know the column names in advance. Refer the updated post and screenshot

Comment: Hello, I am able to do this now. Thanks for your help. Much appreciated. I am marking @gordon Linoff answer as solution. However, it would be helpful if the answer could be updated with `percentile` function for readers to follow. I used something like this `percentile_cont(0.25) within group (order by value asc) as "25pc",
       percentile_cont(0.75) within group (order by value asc) as "75pc"`

Comment: @Gordon Lindoff - Can you help me with this related post?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60087614/unable-to-upload-csv-file-to-a-postgresql-database